# How and Where can a declaration go so it can be used by two methods in Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio

I'm a newcomer to Java and Android Studio so am still learning, so sorry if this question is simplistic. I have recently discovered that as an alternative to coding an onClickListener in the activity.java file to respond to a button click, it can be done more simply with an android:onClick="*method name*" in the corresponding layout.xml file. I have already looked at this site's questions relating to the pros and cons of each method, but that is not my problem. My problem is, where and how can I declare a text field that is used by two methods without having to declare it in each method?
The code that follows is as minimal as possible. There are two buttons and one text view. If I attempt to put "TextView themessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.message);" anywhere other than in both methods, I get the dreaded "Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.Window.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference".
Is there anywhere and any way to make a single declaration that can be used by both methods without generating this exception?

**Extract from the .xml file**

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Click me"
    android:id="@+id/topbutton"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="88dp"
    android:onClick="doit"/>

 <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="***"
    android:id="@+id/message"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

 <Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Again"
    android:id="@+id/againbutton"
    android:layout_below="@+id/message"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="63dp"
    android:onClick="starit"/>
```

**Top end extract from the .java file**

```
package com.example.owner.clickme;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
   {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   }

   public void doit (View v)
   {
       TextView themessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.message);
       themessage.setText("Well clicked, Sir!");
   }

   public void starit (View v)
   {
       TextView themessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.message);
       themessage.setText("****");
   }
   .
   . etc.
```

Comment: Declar the textView in a global scoop not inside a method

Comment: You should declare the TextView in the declaration area (so that is's visible inside your Class). Then find it in the `onCreate()` method. Then use it in your methods, without having the exception.

Comment: I've tried that, Frank. I've placed the "TextView themessage = etc." line just below the open brace in the public class declaration but I get the same runtime exception.

Comment: Frank. I now understand your comment, which was of course quite correct. It's the two stage thing I didn't get at first. Got it now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is common practice in Android to instantiate any Views within the `onCreate`, or where you inflate the main content view.

So, make a  field inside of `MainActivity` like so

```
private TextView themessage;
```

Within `onCreate` get the TextView

```
theMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.message);
```

Then you are free to use `theMessage` across both methods.

---

All in all, it looks like this

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
   private TextView themessage;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
   {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       themessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.message);
   }

   public void doit (View v)
   {
       themessage.setText("Well clicked, Sir!");
   }

   public void starit (View v)
   {
       themessage.setText("****");
   }
}
```

Comment: Many thanks, Cricket_007. That explanation was most helpful. And of course, it works!

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want to do is have the TextField as member of your activity class.

Something like that probably

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView theMessage;    

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   theMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.message);
}

public void doit () {
   theMessage.setText("Well clicked, Sir!");
}

public void starit() {
   themessage.setText("****");
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much, KevDev. Your solution worked, of course. Sorry I can't click your answer too!